# Per-project npmrc :: How do I do this?

Tags: node.js, npm

If this is my project layout:

- package.json
- .npmrc
- /client
- /server

and I want npm to install modules to:

- /server/node_modules

what should I set my prefix to?

Right now my .npmrc has: `prefix = ./server` but with this it just installs to directory anyway and puts an empty node_modules folder in the prefix destination. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind. I just read this [link](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6358).

Edit: It simply can't be done yet, even though in their [change log](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) it says per-project npmrc support was available in v1.4.11.

It works in the CLI , so `npm install package --prefix ./folder` will put node_modules folder with package into prefix destination, which isn't very useful. Using --save with that will not update dependencies in package.json, either.

Comment: so... delete the question. or provide a real answer, unless you want to be downvoted.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was searching quite a while why it does not work as expected. Your answer cleared that up